# Can MATLAB apply a function to an array of objects

Tags: arrays, oop, class, function, matlab

I have an array of objects, all of the same class.
Is it possible to apply a function (defined in the methods section in the class) to all the objects in the array at once?
for example, the class definition is:

```
classdef myClass
        properties
            x=0;
        end

        methods
            function obj=plus1(obj)
                obj.x=obj.x+1;
            end
        end

    end
```

Now I can create an object A of class myClass:

```
A=myClass;
```

and apply the method plus1:

```
A=A.plus1;
```

However, if I create an array of objects of the same class:

```
A(1,10)=myClass;
```

is it possible to apply 'plus1' to the 10 objects of A at once?

something like:

```
A(:)=A(:).plus1;
```

Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 1):

You may use `arrayfun`

```
>> A = arrayfun( @(x) x.plus1, A );
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as the method `plus1` is defined for arrays of objects, it will work:

```
    methods
        function obj=plus1(objList)
            for obj = objList(:)'
               obj.x=obj.x+1;
            end
        end
    end
```

Now you can call `A = plus1(A)` or `A=A.plus1` even if `A` is an array of objects.

Comment: I'm not sure this quite works; I think some values may get mis-assigned. Noted in the chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26329/discussion-between-david-and-jonas